# How can I find the MAC address of my Wi-Fi interface?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-zero-w

I want to determine the MAC-address of my Wi-Fi interface on a Raspberry Pi Z W running Raspbian Lite.

Is there a command that I can run to tell me this? Is there a device in the `/proc` tree that will disclose it?

Comment: Enter in terminal `ifconfig wlan0` At the end of the first line should be the hardware address aka MAC.

Comment: @LotPings You could make that an answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following is a fragment of a bash script I use to determine the MAC of Ethernet, or if this does not exist of WiFi (for Pi Zero W).

It does not rely on `ifconfig` or any other method of detecting allocated IP, and just needs the system to detect the networking hardware.

This works for Jessie, Stretch or Buster

```
# Find MAC of eth0, or if not exist wlan0
if [ -e /sys/class/net/eth0 ]; then
    MAC=$(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address)
elif [ -e /sys/class/net/enx* ]; then
    MAC=$(cat /sys/class/net/enx*/address)
else
    MAC=$(cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address)
fi
```

Basically you could use `MAC=$(cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address)` to find the MAC of inbuilt WiFi on Pi3 or Pi Zero W.

`MAC=$(cat /sys/class/net/wlx*/address)` should work on WiFi dongles on Stretch, but you could easily adapt the above to work on both Jessie or Stretch for WiFi and Ethernet.

Comment: Very good answer. Thank you! Does Raspbian Stretch use predictable network interface names? Do they affect the naming of the structure under `/sys/class/net`?

Comment: @Bex It depends; a fresh install uses predictable network interface names by default, I do not know about upgrades. It is simple to restore former behaviour, see [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) for detail. Whatever name is selected by the hardware enumeration process should be shown. There are several methods of modifying this process.

Answer (score 10):

Enter in terminal/console `ifconfig wlan0` At the end of the first line should be the hardware address aka MAC.

Here a sample output (German locale):

```
pi@RasPi0w-1:~ $ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse b8:27:eb:xx:xx:xx
...
```

Comment: I have upvoted this answer - but I don't think `ifconfig` is a good alternative going forward.

Comment: Agreed, luckily there are two alternatives.

Answer (score 7):

Many distros is replacing `ifconfig` with `ip` so I would discourage the use of `ifconfig`.

To show the wlan0 interface:

```
ip link show wlan0
```

or

```
cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address
```

Ref: https://www.linux.com/learn/replacing-ifconfig-ip

Comment: I'm pretty sure `ifconfig` will still be available for many years. Removing it will save a measly 800 kB, breaking a lot of old scripts.

Comment: Problem is, that person would want a salary.

Comment: To continue to use a deprecated command in new implementations is sad. I have seen this in work related situations, and its like pushing the problem in front of you, and at a point in time it will get to big! Start dealing with it instead!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP has plenty of time to run `ifconfig` before Raspbian gets rid of it ;) Not that I'm against `ip` of course, it's just that you said that many distros are ditching `ifconfig`, but AFAIK all distros compatible with the RPi still have it.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, Fun that you mention OP, he is NOT asking for ifconfig, check the original question....

Comment: In this case, `ip link show` is probably more appropriate than `ip addr show`.

Comment: In my desktop system I run Debian Stretch, that does not seem to have `ifconfig` by default anymore, Raspbian Stretch seem to have it. I prefer `ip` over `ifconfig`, though I think Bob is right in saying that `link` is probably more appropriate than `addr` in this context. The solution I did go for, though, was to read it from `/sys/class/net/wlan0/address` - no additional parsing necessary.  Additionally, I write it as `cat /sys/class/net/wl*/address` in a naïve attempt to make it save for the coming "predicable network interface names".

Comment: @Bex CentOS 7, Debian 9 (Stretch) have dropped ifconfig in stock, but you can install it afterwards.

Comment: @Bob I agree that link is more appropriate. I will change the answer accordingly.